# UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, get, bearer-token

I'm trying to make a GET request passing a bearer token as authentication.

I try to pass the token with:

```
$response = Http::get($url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]);
```

as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests)

When I check the value of the variables, I get:

```
$token : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MDc0NTI0NzksInVzZXJuYW1lIjoic3VuY2hhaW4iLCJvcmdOYW1lIjoib3JnMCIsImlhdCI6MTYwNzQxNjQ3OX0.LUTFZh8Em13f3cQ8TpxgayVRC9XvVHyczOhQXARxk48"

$url : "https://example.com/channels/common/chaincodes/main?peer=org0/peer0&args=%5B%222020-12-01T22%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C+%222020-12-01T22%3A30%3A00Z%22%5D&fcn=GetMeasuresBetween"
```

But when I copy paste those values in Postman, GET is working and I can get my data, which means data is correct, and the way I execute my GET request might be incorrect.

Where am I wrong ? It seems all good to me !

Comment: actually in the question you are using guzzle method of doing it but for Http wrapper class, so it is not working but in answer you are using the defined method of HTTP client class, though internally it does call guzzle

Comment: Yep, in the docs, it is using: $client->request, not http::get

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

```
        $response = Http::withToken($token)->get($url, [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'peer' => $this->peer,
        'args' => $arrayArgs,
        'fcn' => "GetMeasuresBetween",
    ]);
```

Or, you may use guzzle, and initialize

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $this->url]);

$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'peer' => $this->peer,
        'args' => $arrayArgs,
        'fcn' => "GetMeasuresBetween",
]);
```

I don't know why it is not working the first way, but it is now working !